# Take a call - meaning in the following context

Tags: meaning-in-context

Context:

> Friend 1: Why don't you go for a second opinion. Its hightime.
>   Friend 2: Yes, right, I got to take a call on that.

Here is the usage "take a call" right instead of "I have to a take a decision"?

Also,

> Friend 2: Yes, right, I got to make a call on that.

Here is the usage "make a call" right instead of "I have to a take a decision"?

Which is the right usage? Please clarify.

Comment: Neither of them rolls off the tongue as idiom.  "Take a call" usually means to willingly speak on the phone, while "make a call" usually means to make a judgement (not just a decision).  Option 1 looks definitely incorrect, but Option 2 could be right in certain circumstances.  And further - you never "take a decision", you only make one.

Comment: http://www.usingenglish.com/forum/threads/104858-To-take-call-on,
http://www.answers.com/Q/What_is_the_meaning_for_take_a_call_on_this

i have searched in google earlier and found these articles.

Answer (score 1):

Oddly, there is a sense where "take a call" means "not decide", vaguely similar to a sense of the idiom "take a rain check".  I suspect it somehow relates to umpiring in sports, but I don't know what the specific analogy would be.

It's impossible to be sure which of the several senses of "take a call" was intended in the OP's snippet, but my guess is that it meant "I need to defer the decision until I get more information (presumably from the second opinion)".

Answer (score 1):

"Take a call" is a phrase specific to Indian English. It means the same thing as "make a call" which is to make a decision or a judgement.

Answer (score -3):

"Take call on" means "take decision", but it's a bit informal and creates confusion to many. But those who boast of their English knowledge use this phrase a lot.

Comment: No, it's make a call on something, not take a call on something.Taking a call  means accepting a phone call not making a decision.